# ExtJS 4.2: Adding a New Selection on a BoxSelect on the Fly

Tags: extjs, multi-select

I have a form that has a field that gets populated by my store:

```
Ext.define('EcommBackoffice.store.TransactionProviderStatus', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  autoLoad: true,
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'resources/data/providerstatus.json',
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      root: 'providerstatus'
    }
  },
  fields: ['id', 'name']

});
```

My store contains a simple list of items:

{
  providerstatus: [{
    id: "EXPIRED",
    name: "EXPIRED"
  }, {
    id: "ERROR",
    name: "ERROR"
  }, {
    id: "FRAUD",
    name: "FRAUD"
  }, {
    id: "PAID",
    name: "PAID"
  }, {
    id: "UNCONFIRMED",
    name: "UNCONFIRMED"
  }]
}

Inside my form, the above store is then populated by a BoxSelect:

```
{
  xtype: 'boxselect',
  name: 'providerstatus',
  fieldLabel: oMe.providerstatusField,
  width: 468,
  store: 'TransactionProviderStatus',
  displayField: 'name',
  valueField: 'id',
  minChars: 2,
  typeAhead: true
}
```

While this perfectly works, I also intend to add more items while the user types new values in it. Note that this BoxSelect is a multi-selection. Currently, when I type in random values on it, it simply clears it out.

How do I set up this particular field in such a way that I will be able to add more items, and include it as part of the data that will be passed on submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `forceSelection:false` for this boxselect.

When forceSelection is false, new records can be created by the user as they are typed. These records are not added to the combo's store. Multiple new values may be added by separating them with the delimiter, and can be further configured using the createNewOnEnter and createNewOnBlur configuration options.

Also check `createNewOnEnter` and `createNewOnBlur`

[Create new on Enter for Box Select](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Tag-cfg-createNewOnEnter)

Comment: I added both `createNewOnEnter` and `createNewOnBlur`, and that did it. Tried the former initially, but it did not do anything. Also set `forceSelection: false`. Thanks!